# Why can't a mutable interface/class inherit from an immutable one?

Tags: object-oriented, inheritance, immutability

I've heard people say things like "B can't inherit from A because A is immutable and B is mutable".

My understanding of inheritance in Object-Oriented Programming is that you use it to add behaviors/methods, such as `set` methods.

```
interface A {
   getX(): X
}

interface B extends A {
   setX()
}
```

You can't remove methods/functionality inherited from other interfaces/classes, only override them.  Mutability seems like added functionality (e.g. adding `setters`).  Adding mutability may be unwise in general, but it's making a subclass do something the parent cannot, which is how OOP is supposed to work, no?  Is there something special about mutability that changes that?

I assume I'm hearing the above statement from smart people.  Am I misinterpreting something?  What am I missing?  I usually deal in the context of the JVM (Java/Kotlin), if that makes any difference.

Comment: Look up Liskov Substitution Principle. In your example, it's not wrong to inherit B from A *per se*. But imagine A is a part of some larger framework that you can plug into by implementing this interface; if the documentation for A says something like "implementations are required to be immutable in X", then allowing X to be set in B might lead to unpredictable behavior, like a subtle, hard-to-find bug, or straight up crash your program, when a B instance is plugged into the framework. This can happen within your own code as well, in all kinds of ways (it's not just about immutability).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I responded here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/442640/what-does-it-mean-when-someone-says-b-cant-inherit-from-a-because-a-is-immuta#comment972720_442641

Comment: @rwong On what basis are you making that rather sweeping statement about somebody else's question?

Comment: @IMSoP: Sorry for trying to put words in OP's mouth. I was just hoping to clarify the question to any StackExchange users that this question is much deeper than what it superficially seems, hopefully so that users will not downvote the question before they understand the depth of the question.

Comment: I wanted to write an answer citing some concrete examples from .NET (= the OO framework I am familiar with), only to discover that they are terribly inconsistent. For example, the [`IReadOnlyList<T>` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=net-7.0) is defined as *"represent[ing] a list in which the number and order of list elements is read-only"*, which is just plain wrong (given the fact that [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0) implements this interface). 1/2

Comment: It would have been more correct to call it something like `IReadableList<T>` or `IListReader<T>` and define it as, e.g., *"a common interface for accessing the number of elements as well as the elements themselves in a mutable or immutable list"*. 2/2

Comment: There's too many insightful answers to change the question now, but reading through them all shows that I should have been more careful in my wording.  I was specifically interested in when a mutable interface extends an *unmodifiable* one.  Saying "immutable" implied a guarantee while "unmodifiable" is more a lack of setters.  I wonder if some of us are making conflicting assumptions.

Comment: @GlenPeterson: That case (lack of setters, but no immutability "contract") is easy: Yes, it's fine to add setters. An example from the Java class library would be the (mutable) `StringBuilder` class, which implements the (read-only) `CharSequence` interface.

Comment: You say inheritance is about adding behaviors, but isn't immutability a behavior?  It's sort of a glass half empty/full thing, since you could view immutability OR mutability as an added "feature".  But I would suggest immutability is certainly worthy of being considered a behavior, especially given that is has to be explicitly invoked.

Comment: @tarheels, FYI in Rails evidently they have decided `String to inherit from `ImmutableString`  https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Type/String.html

Answer (score 44):

> Adding mutability may be unwise in general, but it's making a subclass do something the parent cannot, which is how OOP is supposed to work, no?

A key concept in OOP is that of *substitutability*: if I promise you that I will give you an object of class `A`, I can *safely substitute* any sub-class of `A`, and your code will still *behave as expected*. This is often summed up by referencing the "[Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)":

> Let `ϕ(x)` be a property provable about objects `x` of type `T`. Then `ϕ(y)` should be true for objects `y` of type `S` where `S` is a subtype of `T`.

To paraphrase to your example:

> Anything you can prove about the behaviour of class `A` should also be true of sub-class `B`.

As you rightly say, that means you can't remove methods, only add new ones; similarly, you can't narrow the input allowed in those methods, only widen it. Less obviously, it means that you can't *widen the output* of those methods: there is a provable behaviour of `A` that `getX` will return an instance of `X`; if `B::getX` returned a value that is not an instance of `X`, it would violate that behaviour, so `B` would not be *substitutable* for `A`.

This concept of "contravariance of input, covariance of output" is one example of substitutability, but more broadly we can talk about *behavioural sub-typing*: the idea that code relies not just on the structure of the types it works with, but general behavioural properties. Changing these behaviours in sub-types, even if the language does not provide tools to enforce them, is generally a bad idea.

To return to the question then: if immutability is a "provable property" of class `A`, then it should also be true for sub-class `B`. To make it less abstract, we can try to think of a scenario where code might *rely on* this property:

- Consider a container object which has a large list of objects.
- If two objects are identical and immutable, you can save memory by storing two pointers to the same object, rather than two copies.
- If you know that class `A` is immutable, and your list only accepts instances of class `A`, you can implement this optimisation unconditionally.
- Since `B` is a sub-class of `A`, two currently-identical instances of `B` can be added to the list. They will be de-duplicated, and only one instance stored.
- However, since `B` is mutable, one of those instances can be mutated from outside the list. When they are retrieved, they should now be different, but the list will return one of them twice.

Comment: My difficulty comes where mutability is not represented in the type system or interface hierarchy.  Mutability changes the *behavior* of `getX` *over time*, but does not "widen the output" from a domain/range set-theory perspective.  It seems to me that mutability is outside the scope of what's guaranteed by OOP or any type system that I'm aware of.  Part of my confusion may be whether we're talking about classes and inheritance vs. types and interface extension.  Does it matter?

Comment: @GlenPeterson I've added to the answer slightly, to clarify two things: firstly, I'm talking about the *behaviours* of types, not just their range of values; secondly, I'm talking about *design principles*, which apply whether or not any particular language enforces them. The example at the end was supposed to illustrate this: it's not about the mutable sub-class being impossible, it's about it being *a bad idea* because it might break assumptions in other code.

Comment: @GlenPeterson Also, you say "Mutability changes the behavior of getX over time"; that is *not* the type of behaviour I'm talking about. I'm saying that the behaviour of class `B` *as a whole* is different from the behaviour of class `A` *as a whole*. Specifically, class `A` has the behaviour "an instance will never change state"; but class `B` has the behaviour "any instance may change state at any time". You are right that this cannot be inferred from the type system of most languages, but it can still be documented by the author of the interface, and then *relied on*, as in the List example.

Comment: @IMSoP: "whether or not any particular language enforces them" / "it's not about the mutable sub-class being impossible" – In fact, since the LSP is about *runtime behavior*, it is impossible to guarantee it in the general case. The most obvious example is when your supertype has the property "subroutine X always terminates", then checking whether a subtype violates the LSP is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Comment: There has always been a schism in defining the boundaries of LSP. Should LSP care about *provable properties* in the human sense (i.e. a programmer or computer scientist can verify that from reading the code and logical reasoning), or in the compiler construction sense (i.e. subject to the capabilities of static analysis technologies of the day)? Both understandings are valid, and we just need to clarify during discussions.

Comment: @rwong I have only ever seen it stated as a theoretical principle, and an aim when designing tools. I don't agree that it is valid to start from a practical implementation and reverse engineer a set of principles based on one l what it enforces.

Comment: @GlenPeterson - "It seems to me that mutability is outside the scope of what's guaranteed by OOP or any type system that I'm aware of." - you are right, generally, not all elements of a type specification can be expressed via language features or the type system. So, a compiler will help you as much as it can, but it will happily let you plug in code that will potentially cause something to break (either the immediate client, or some other part of the system). Which is why we try to cover our grounds with tests (they are supposed to exercise if an implementation adheres to the abstract spec).

Comment: Languages can *allow* programmers to declare certain attributes (e.g. the attribute of absolute immutability, or conditional immutability (e.g. certain ("mutating") methods on this class are never called), even if the type system is not 100% fool-proof. There was once a famous quote in programming language design that (paraphrased here) languages are designed to help the gentleman write good code, not to stop the determined from doing something stupid (e.g. exploiting loopholes in the type system). Of course with computer security in mind, the type system better live up to a better standard.

Comment: Presumably you created B because you needed something like A, but different.  That difference could always cause incompatibilities.  Where do you draw the line?  When selecting examples, equality and sort order spring to mind as common bug factories.  Can a sorted map be equal to an unsorted map if their contents are the same?  Map says "yes" but SortedMap might say, "no" because it cares about the order. Same thing comparing Point2D to Point3D, what's Point2D's Z coordinate and does it matter for equality?  I guess I just see mutability as one of many 'gotchas' inherent in inheritance.

Comment: @GlenPeterson Looking at the evolutionary history of [the Python `typing` (type annotations)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), one can see that they retroactively added annotations to clarify the expectations of a subtype. Retroactive means that implementation *preceded* the annotation. Whenever there is a realization that a previous definition of a certain type annotation wasn't worded correctly, a community process kickstarts to revise that wording. Python use typing as a guard rail so that programmers can hold onto it; it doesn't use typing as a cage to constrain programmers.

Comment: Join the Discussion: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141072/discussion-between-glenpeterson-and-jorg-w-mittag

Comment: @GlenPeterson: You are conflating two different things here. "I want something like A but different" is about *code re-use*. You want to create something similar to A without having to re-implement all of A. But whether or not an ordered map should be equal to an ordered map with the same elements but in different order, that is a question of its *contract*, i.e. a question of *type*. Nobody can fault you for conflating those two things, because Java, C#, C++, Kotlin, etc. conflate them, too, but they *are* different things. The fact that a particular language *forces* you to take one with …

Comment: … the other does *not* mean that the distinction is irrelevant. In fact, I would argue, languages that conflate the two make it *more* important to be clear about which is which, not less.

Comment: @rwong I totally agree that languages can, either through necessity or choice, implement more relaxed rules. I just don't think it's reasonable to say that "in Python, LSP means X; in Java, LSP means Y" - the *principle* doesn't change, it's just up to the language whether it enforces that principle, and up to the programmer whether they follow it even if not enforced.

Comment: @GlenPeterson "Presumably you created B because you needed something like A, but different." – I never use inheritance that way. If I create a subclass of the `GaugeTester` class, it's not because I need something that's like a gauge tester but different. It's because I need something that **is** a gauge tester, but which isn't completely described by the `GaugeTester` class. Maybe the `GaugeTester` class describes any kind of gauge tester, and I need a gauge tester that sends a voltage to the gauge and checks that the needle is in the correct position.

Comment: You seem to have confounded immutability of the property with immutability of the class.

Comment: @Joshua I'm not sure what you mean. The title of the question says that "A is immutable but B is mutable", those are the names of the classes, not of any particular property.

Comment: @IMSoP: I really want IList: IReadOnlyList

Comment: @Joshua I really want `Square : Rectangle`, but `Square s; s.width() = 10; assert(s.height()==10);` holds, while `Rectangle r; r.width() = 10;` does not guarantee `r.height()==10`.  So a mutable rectangle is not a mutable square; code that is 100% valid when passed a mutable Square will fail when passed a mutable Rectangle.  **Inheritance doesn't solve every problem.**

Comment: @rwong IIRC, one of the goals of Ada was that the language make it hard for bad programmers to violate interface specs. The intended use was a senior S/W architect designing the protocols, and then delegating implementation to hoards of mediocre programmers. It never caught on outside certain safety-critical applications.

Comment: My experience with C# is that, to declare (additive) capability, one uses interfaces (and interface inheritance / extension), whereas to enforce access control (which sometimes involves taking away or denying capability offered by the leaf implementation), one uses a decorator class that implements exactly the same interface (minus a few) and omit the methods that are to be denied. If omitting methods is not an option, InvalidOperationException is typically thrown.

Answer (score 24):

> My understanding of Inheritance in Object-Oriented Programming is that you use it to add behaviors/methods, such as `set` methods.

A lot of mainstream object-oriented languages, and Java and Kotlin are no exception, lump multiple separate things together under the single mechanism of *Inheritance*.

So, in some sense you are right: inheritance *is* used to add behaviors, in particular add behaviors in such a way that you only need to describe the *difference* between the behaviors of the subclass to the superclass. This is sometimes called *Differential Code Re-Use*.

However, the problem is that this is not the *only thing* inheritance does. Inheritance also does something else: it creates a *Subtyping* relationship between the superclass and the subclass. In other words, `B` is *not just* a *subclass* of `A`, it is also a *subtype* of `A`. Which means inheritance is not just used to add *behaviors*, it is also used to add *contracts*.

There *are* languages where those two aspects are separate, where there are separate mechanisms for differential code re-use and subtyping. But they are not mainstream.

(Unless you count dynamic languages which *only* have differential code re-use as part of the language, and the typing only happens in the programmer's head.)

> You can't remove methods/functionality inherited from other interfaces/classes, only override them.  Mutability seems like added functionality (e.g. adding `setters`).  Adding mutability may be unwise in general, but it's making a subclass do something the parent cannot, which is how OOP is supposed to work, no?  Is there something special about mutability that changes that?

If you are looking at it *only* from the point of view of differential code re-use, then you are correct: this is exactly what it is designed for. You can re-use the code from `A` and you only define what are the *differences* between `B` and `A`. But the problem is that the only way to achieve differential code re-use in Java and/or Kotlin is inheritance, but inheritance *also* creates a subtyping relationship. And that means, that `B` needs to obey all the rules for subtyping.

So, what are those rules for subtyping?

Today, the best way we know how to characterize *subtyping*, especially in the presence of *mutability* and *aliasing*, is what is commonly called the [*Liskov Substitution Principle* or *LSP*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

The LSP was introduced by [Barbara Liskov](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Liskov) in a keynote address at the [OOPSLA conference](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/OOPSLA) 1987, titled [*Data Abstraction and Hierarchy*](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/%7Enr/cs257/archive/barbara-liskov/data-abstraction-and-hierarchy.pdf):

> If for each object *o<sub>1</sub>* of type **S** there is an object *o<sub>2</sub>* of type **T** such that for all programs ***P*** defined in terms of **T**, the behavior of ***P*** is unchanged when *o<sub>1</sub>* is substituted for *o<sub>2</sub>*, then **S** is a subtype of **T**.

A similar definition is also given in [*A Behavioral Notion of Subtyping*](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ewing/publications/LiskovWing94.pdf) (1994):

> Let ***ϕ(x)*** be a property provable about objects *x* of type **T**. Then ***ϕ(y)*** should be true for objects *y* of type **S** where **S** <⦂ **T**.

Now, these are some pretty abstract definitions. The main advantage of these definitions, which are based on the *behavior* of the programs, is that these definitions also work for mutability and aliasing. Earlier approaches were less precise, e.g. the co- and contra-variance rules for functions do not work with mutability or aliasing, and the proof-theoretic approach by [Bertrand Meyer](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_Meyer) only works for mutability.

Thankfully, we can derive some rules which are simpler to interpret than those abstract definitions:

There are three static restrictions for subroutine signatures:

1. Subroutines are *contravariant* in their *parameter* types.
2. Subroutines are *covariant* in their *result* types.
3. Subroutines in a subtype can only throw exceptions which are subtypes of the supertype's subroutine's exceptions.

#1 and #2 are not new, they are simply the standard variance rules for functions – they had been known for decades. #3 was already stated by Meyer, and is actually the same thing as #2 if you consider exceptions part of the result type of a subroutine.

So far, none of this should be surprising.

What's more interesting, are the four *behavioral* restrictions. These are restrictions on the *runtime behavior* of instances of subtypes. They are stated in the form of *invariants* (statements that must always be true, where "always" means "after construction and before and after every subroutine call"), *preconditions* (statements that must be true before every subroutine call), and *postconditions* (statements that must be true after every subroutine call):

1. Preconditions cannot be strengthened in a subtype.
2. Postconditions cannot be weakened in a subtype.
3. Invariants must be preserved in a subtype.
4. The *History Constraint*.

#1 and #2 are again just re-statements of the signature constraints #1 and #2 (which are just the variance rules for functions) in terms of behavioral contracts expressed as preconditions and postconditions. #3 was already known to Meyer.

One of the two *big things* and big innovations about Liskov's and Wing's way of phrasing this, is the *History Constraint*. The history constraint says that, *an observer who observes an instance of the subtype through the interface of the supertype must not be allowed to observe a history that he could not observe of an instance of the supertype*. (The other bing thing is the idea of "substitutability", i.e. that `B` is a subtype of `A` **IFF** instances of `B` can be substituted by instances of `A`.)

There's a lot to unpack here. So, we have "an observer", which is simply a program **O**. This program is passed an instance of `A`, and it can call any subroutine it wants, however often it wants, whenever it wants. Now, you pass it an instance of `B`, which is perfectly fine, since `B` is a subtype of `A`, and thus, any instance of `B` is also an instance of `A`.

We also have a different program, the "manipulator" **M**, which gets passed the same instance of `B`, and which can use any subroutine of `B` to manipulate this instance.

What the history constraint says, is that no matter what crazy things **M** does to the instance and no matter what clever tricks **O** uses to inspect the instance, it must be *impossible* for **O** to observe a history that it could not observe if **M** only knew about `A`.

And that is the problem with your code. Your code does not violate any of the signature constraints and it does not violate any precondition or postcondition, i.e. it does not violate the first two behavioral constraints.

It *may* or may not violate behavioral constraint #3 regarding invariants. Unfortunately, you have not really shown how your interfaces are used and what your requirements are, so we don't actually know what the invariants of `A` are. But it is *possible* that `A` *could* have the invariant that `X` never changes after construction. If that were the case, then `B` would violate the constraint that invariants must be preserved.

This, BTW, demonstrates an important lesson about *practical* implications of the LSP. The LSP itself talks about "for *all* programs the behavior is unchanged" and it simply mentions "provable properties". But in a real world, that is too restrictive. For example, an important reason for subtyping is that subtypes being special cases may allow more efficient implementations of subroutines. But, being faster is technically a changed behavior, and thus the LSP wouldn't allow you to make specialized, faster, subtypes.

Similarly, "any provable property" is incredibly broad, since there may be a lot of weird, obscure properties that are provable about a program.

That's why, in the real world, when we analyze whether a subtype violates the LSP, we must always look at the *contract* of the supertype. In other words, instead of looking at *all possible programs* and *all possible provable properties*, we are only looking at the subset of programs that we *actually want to write* and we are only looking at the subset of *desirable*, *relevant* properties. And the way we do that, is by specifying the contract of the supertype. Ideally, in some formal language, but more often than not simply in the documentation, or even implicitly, i.e. without even stating the contract out loud.

Since you don't specify the contract of `A`, in particular not its invariants, we can't really tell whether or not `B` violates them or not. The only thing we *can* tell is that it *would* be possible to specify an invariant that is guaranteed to hold for `A` but is violated by `B`. In the pure phrasing of Liskov, this is enough to be a violation, but in reality, we would look at what the *actual* guarantees are that `A` makes in its documentation.

However, whether or not `B` violates the invariant constraint is irrelevant, because it *definitely* violates the history constraint, in a rather trivial manner: since `A` is immutable, it is impossible to construct a history where `X` has different values at different points in time, yet, that *is* possible with `B`. Therefore, `B` violates the history constraint, which means `B` is *not* a subtype of `A`. (Or, since Kotlin is not actually able to prevent you from doing this, we should alternately say that *it is not type-safe to make `B` a subtype of `A`*.)

This shows *why* Liskov's and Wing's innovation was so important. The old variance rules for functions could not deal with mutability. The proof-theoretic approach of Meyer could not deal with aliasing. Only the behavioral approach plus the history constraint can actually deal with the problem caused by mutability plus aliasing.

Why is this important? Where can this break?

Imagine, `A` is written in 2018 by a programmer in Brazil. In 2019, a programmer in New Zealand writes a nifty library `foolib` which uses `A`. Because `A` is immutable, this programmer can use some clever tricks to speed up their library, like memoizing the value of `X` and never ask for it again. In 2020, a programmer in Hungary writes `B`. In 2021, a programmer in Canada writes a nifty library `barlib` which uses `B`. Since `B` is mutable, they can do some nifty tricks like storing intermediate results in `X` to speed up their library. In 2022, you write some program using `B` which uses both theses nifty libraries. So, you construct a single instance of `B` and pass that to both libraries to do their nifty processing.

Boom. `foolib` blows up because `barlib` is manipulating what `foolib` thinks is a perfectly safe immutable `A` instance behind its back.

Even worse: `foolib` *doesn't* blow up, but gives wrong results!

Problems like this can only happen when you have *aliasing* (i.e. different pieces of code referring to the same instance) and *mutability*. And only the history constraint can protect you from this.

Let's examine one of your questions again:

> it's making a subclass do something the parent cannot, which is how OOP is supposed to work, no?  Is there something special about mutability that changes that?

Now we can look at this a bit more precisely. The problem is not that `B` can do something that `A` cannot do. The problem is that `B` can do something that *breaks `A`'s contract*. The problem is not "doing something that `A` *cannot* do", but "doing something that `A` *shouldn't be able to do*".

You are not *merely* adding new behavior. You are also changing existing behavior. For example, adding a *new*, mutable field, would have been perfectly fine. The precise problem is that through allowing to mutate `X`, you have not only *added* the subroutine `setX`, you have also implicitly *changed* the behavior of `getX`, which before had the guarantee that it always returns the same value, and you have now removed this guarantee.

Comment: "Inheritance is not just used to add behaviors, it is also used to add contracts."  I've never heard that before.  What is your source for this assertion?  Or in what context (which languages), is this true?

Comment: Oh, Meyer/Eiffel.  Got it.  Thanks!

Comment: @GlenPeterson: "Or in what context (which languages), is this true?" – There are many languages where inheritance is not only used for differential code re-use. For example, in Java, the `extends` keyword creates *both* a *subclass* (i.e. a container for methods) and a *subtype* (i.e. a set of guarantees, IOW, a contract). There are only a very small number of mostly academic languages where implementation inheritance can be performed without subtyping. Before the addition of interface default methods, it was possible to create subtypes without inheriting methods by extending an interface, …

Comment: … but it was never possible to inherit methods without also creating a subtype (since every class is also a type in Java).

Comment: @GlenPeterson: The four behavioral constraints come from the Liskov Substitution Principle. In Liskov's papers, they are of course phrased with lots of Greek letters and logical symbols, but that's what they are saying. See, e.g. Figure 1 and Figure 5 in [*A Behavioral Notion of Subtyping*](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ewing/publications/LiskovWing94.pdf) for two subtly different definitions of the subtyping constraints.

Comment: Part of my problem might be the JVM curse/blessing of `.equals()`  and `.compareTo()`.  Most subclassing breaks these.  Certainly adding any meaningful field does.  `point2D.equals(point3D)` but `!point3D.equals(point2D)` is the classic example (point2D doesn't know about the `z` coordinate, but point3D requires it).  `.compareTo()` is generally broken in the same circumstances.  Another good one is that you'd expect SortedMap to care about sort order in its equals method, but in the Java standard library it doesn't (in order to be compatible with Map).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141072/discussion-between-glenpeterson-and-jorg-w-mittag).

Comment: Great answer! One small nit that stood out to me: would you characterize languages such as F# or Ocaml as "out of the mainstream"? IIRC they separate polymorphism from reuse, but I would consider them to be well inside the mainstream of line-of-business general application programming languages. Maybe its simply that you and I have a different idea of what is in the mainstream.

Comment: @EricLippert: I must admit I am not nearly as familiar with them as I should be, especially given that I soaked up every video with Don Syme, Brian Beckman, Erik Meijer, Yuri Gurevich, and co. on Channel 9 10–15 years ago. Maybe I should have written "mainstream OO languages" because, even though both of those languages *are* object-oriented, the "mainstream perception" for them is as functional languages. Maybe the OP's mention of JVM blinded me, as I did briefly consider Scala, but it also ties together inheritance and subtyping, it just does it with slightly more style.

Comment: re: the history principle, would that not imply that in for example Java (because I'm most familiar with it), adding anything at all to a subtype breaks LSP?  Because the observer program can use reflection to observe that the object has members not defined in the supertype.

Comment: Arguably, the interface A (as written) is not immutable, just unmodifiable, and implementations are free to be immutable or not (or even pure observers of some outside world property which changes in time). So `foolib`'s optimization is wrong, unless it adds this as an additional documented precondition.

Comment: @JörgWMittag wonderful answer but _in practice_, how could we design an hypothetical `IClock` interface with a `GetCurrentTime()` member? It would break the _history constraint_ even without subtyping. If the language lacks of a formal way to decorate an object as immutable (or - better than nothing - an interface documents this aspect even if it's not enforced) then you cannot safely assume it just because an interface is read-only. 

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: I don't understand. If you have no subtyping, then the LSP and thus the history constraint are completely irrelevant.

Comment: But I'd have subtyping (for the class, if not the interface). For example to allow to adjust the clock. The interface is is just a read-only _view_ (or as _views_ is how I'd interpret it)

Answer (score 11):

Adding setters is neither always strictly adding functionality, nor removing it. Not even if it is for additional state. Rather, it modifies pre-existing functionality.

The crucial point is whether you subvert the inherited contract, which can only be answered by looking at it. Also, most classes are [not designed for inheritance](/q/89073), as that is considerable added and often wasted effort.

If the parent guarantees that certain state of the object, as observed through the interface, or the object itself, is immutable, you are stuck with that.
On the other hand, if it only doesn't provide the interface to modify it itself, you might be able to provide an expanded/additional interface for modification.

Beware of implicit, assumed, or vague contracts though. "I never actually said" will rarely satisfy users.

Comment: Why do you say adding a setter is not strictly adding functionality?

Comment: @nasch Because it also modified pre-existing functionality, in a potentially incompatible way.

Answer (score 3):

An interface is a collection of methods, but it is also a promise about behaviour. The specificity of that promise may vary massively of course.

There is a big difference between

- You can't mutate x.
- Noone can mutate x.

If the documentation for a class or interface says that it is immutable you are breaking that "contract" by creating a mutable subclass or implementing the interface for a mutable class. Implementing a subinterface implies implementing the parent interface, so defining a mutable subinterface of an immutable interface generally makes no sense, there would be no way to implement the interface correctly.

If the documentation for the class or interface does not say anything about mutability then you are not breaking any contract by creating an implementation that allows mutation.

Comment: Besides the aspect of promise, there is also the aspect of request. If a method accepts an object, it can specify what capabilities it requests on this object, by specifying the interface/subtype to use. Whether giving a mutable object to a method (collaborator) that requests to use an object immutably will cause it to puke is a matter of (devils in the) implementation detail, and is typically explained through documentation.

Comment: Particularly, in a language with automatic memory management you can treat references to immutable objects as-if they were straight values. Whereas if someone hands you a reference to a mutable object you have to think carefully about whether you need to make a copy of the object.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is “immutability”? As an example, Objective-C has many classes that just have no methods to explicitly modify their instances. These classes, like NSString, are not immutable as a language feature, but through a lack of mutating accessors. In C++, the same class can have const and non-const instances, with some methods marked so they can be used for const objects. The declaration that the compiler sees does not necessarily match whether the object is actually const or not.

Now take a string class with an expensive hash function whose value is cached after the first use. Caching that value modifies the object, but not the behaviour except for speed. Does that affect mutability?

There may be languages that have explicitly “mutable” and “immutable” classes and don’t allow deriving a mutable from an immutable class. In other languages, you *can* do this but it is “asking for trouble” so you don’t.

Again, in Objective-C, NSMutableString is a subclass of NSString. You are supposed to know the consequences and avoid them. (Making a copy of a String often avoids problems at zero cost for immutable strings, because copy for immutable strings just increases the reference count. If you try to use a mutable string as a dictionary key, an immutable copy will created).

Comment: I have no clue about who downvoted this, but the Objective-C example is really a good one. It shows a) that smart people did inherit mutable from immutable, b) successfully used it in production code, and c) from my experience with it, it worked like a charm.

Comment: I would disagree somewhat with "worked like a charm". There's a common pattern where you create a NSMutableArray, add objects to it, and then return an immutable copy of the array. This is considered a good idea specifically because having mutable classes inherit from the immutable ones is sometimes a source of weird bugs when someone assumes an arbitrary NSArray is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use goto in many modern OO languages like Java, C#, and C++.  Just don't though, mkay?

In your example though the interface just specifies that you can get a value 'X'.  It shouldn't matter to the caller whether the value is mutable or not, or if it's computed from two other values, or reads it from a file, or anything else.  If it provides the ability to get an 'X' value, that fulfils the contract.   Interfaces by their definition aren't immutable, they have to be implemented and the values have to come from somewhere.  Passing around an interface that doesn't include setters to methods that have no reason to be changing the properties makes sense to me.

Immutability makes sense if you want to write programs in a functional style and there are benefits to that approach, but it isn't the only way to program and not the end-all-be-all.  I wouldn't go inheriting interfaces and adding setters for the values if there wasn't a good reason for it though.

Comment: Java does not https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545141/520567 actually I'm shocked to see it ever had it. This is the last language I'd expect to have goto.